# iPhone: I got the warning message " UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated " . what does it mean ? and how can i resolve it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am doing scroll view app for iPhone in xcode with iphone4.3 simulator.
but i got a warning message in the code :

```
-(void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notif
{

if(keyboardVisible)
{
    NSLog(@"keyboard is already visible");
    return;
}

NSLog(@"resizing smaller for keyboard");

NSDictionary* info = [notif userInfo];

//warning message on following line

NSValue* aValue= [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];

CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size ;

CGRect viewFrame= self.view.frame;
viewFrame.size.height-= keyboardSize.height;

scrollView.frame= viewFrame;
keyboardVisible =YES;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` instead.

Answer (score 0):

'Deprecated' warnings are essentially a message from the authors of the library you're using to you, saying "This function or constant has problems and should not be used in the future". Usually the documentation or the header file will list a replacement you should use instead.